# Программно изменить позицию seekbar-a

Tags: android, seekbar

Реализую смену размера шрифта с помощью SeekBar-а. Храню данные в SharedPreferences.

```
private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    public static final String FONT_SIZE = "FONT_SIZE";
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        loadSizeFont();
}

  @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        sizeFont = progress;
        tv_text.setTextSize(sizeFont);
        saveSizeFont();    
    }
   @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
    }


 void saveSizeFont() {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(FONT_SIZE, sizeFont);
        ed.apply();    
    }

    void loadSizeFont() {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int size = (int) sharedPref.getInt(FONT_SIZE, 17);
        tv_text.setTextSize(size);    
    }
```

Размер шрифта сохраняется при выходе из приложения, но когда захожу, размер шрифта, допустим, на 25sp, а ползунок так и стоит на 17sp, как указано ему стоять при первом запуске. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы выставлять при загрузке прогресс `seekBar`'a, вам нужно в `loadSizeFont()` вызывать `seekBar.setProgress(size)`
.